# Covariance matrix with noise

Tags: math, machine-learning

I am a little confused on this matrix:

Assume: y=f+e, where y denotes the final observation, f denotes noise-free data while e denotes Gaussian noise which comes from N(0,sig^2).

We know the training data: {(xi,fi)|i=1,...n}. Then the covariance of y (Ky) equals the covariance of f (K(x,x)) plus the diagnoal noise sig^2*I, where I is the identity matrix (Ky=K(x,x)+sig^2*I).

Could anyone please show me how to derive it?

Comment: Covariance is a relationship between two random variables. What do you mean by "covariance of y"? you refer to a covariance matrix but there are only two variables here. Are you trying to derive something about covariance(y,f)?

Comment: @Sean Owen Thank you for your post and sorry I did not describe the question precisely. The covariance K(x,x) denotes the covariance of the noise-free training data x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use f and x interchangeably, so, f=x? You seem to be talking about the covariance of a random variable with itself, which is just "variance". There is no covariance matrix here -- well, it's a 1x1 matrix with the value "1".

So you are asking why K(y,y) = K(x,x) + sig^2? Well this is because variances add. Var(y) = Var(x+e) = Var(x) + Var(e), and Var(e) = sig^2 is given. By definition, K(y,y) = Var(y) and K(x,x) = Var(x), and you're done.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Would you mind to explain why Var(e)=sig^2*I? (I is the identity matrix.)

Comment: I is "1" in your case. You gave that e is normally distributed with variance sig^2 in the problem. So these are equal by definition.

Comment: I understand what you mean. But please could you have a brief look at:http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/chapters/RW2.pdf  Page16-Equation 2.20;  The covariance is written as: cov(yp,yq)=K(xp,xq)+sig^2*kro(p,q), where kro is a Kronecker delta. No offence but this may indicates: the sig^2 noise will be only added to the diagnoal elements of K(x,x).

Comment: Are the y vectors rather than scalars? No offense but this would make more sense if you explained your problem. The reference is unlike your problem statement.

Comment: Yes, y and f are all vectors rather than scalars and K(x,x) is therefore a matrix.

Comment: OK, makes much more sense. The answer is about the same -- it's because you defined it that way. K(e,e) is by definition sig^2*I given that you wrote N(0,sig^2) because sig is a scalar instead of a covariance matrix and I can only assume you intend the notation to mean sig^2*I.

Comment: Why is the K(y,y) defined as 'K(x,x)+sig^2*I' instead of 'K(x,x)+sig^2'? (Can I assume that: for K(x,x), the diagnoal elements of which are variances, it is only reasonable to add noise to the variance?)

Comment: Think about the units. sig is a scalar. K(x,x) is some n x n matrix. What would it mean to add them?

Comment: I think it is mathematically feasible: [1 1;2 3]+3=[4 4;5 6]...I know it may look rediculars to add the noise to every element of K(x,x), but why it becomes reasonable to add the noise to only diagnoal elements of K(x,x)? How to understand this operation?

Answer (score 0):

You are indeed right. I know what you are facing because I faced the same dilemma a few years back.

When you are adding the white-Gaussian noise to the original signal in additive model, this *actually* implies that each element of the noise vector e affects the corresponding element of the signal vector f. Hence, the noise vector only affects the diagonal of the signal covariance matrix and results in the covariance of y.

Answer (score 0):

y = f + e

Now since cov(a+b,c) = cov(a,c)+cov(b,c):

cov(y_i, y_j) = cov(f_i,f_j) + cov(f_i,e_i) + cov(e_i,f_j) + cov(e_i,e_j)

Now since e and f are independent, and the covariance between independent variables is 0:

cov(y_i, y_j) = cov(f_i,f_j) + cov(e_i,e_j)

If i != j then e_i and e_j will be independent, in which case

cov(y_i, y_j) = cov(f_i,f_j) = k(x_i,x_j)

If i = j then cov(e_i,e_j) = var(e_i) = σ^2

cov(y_i, y_j) = k(x_i,x_j) + σ^2

So Ky is Kx, but when i=j (on the diagonal), the covariance increased by σ^2.

So Ky = Kx + σ^2*I

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).